# Why doesn't this signature for my function work?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

```hs
function :: (Floating a, RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b
function x = floor (sqrt x)
```

Okay so if you look at this function, I specified that `a` can be both `RealFrac` and `Floating` Typeclasses and then `b` is an `Integral`.
This is because of the signatures of `floor` and `sqrt`:

```hs
floor :: (Integral b, RealFrac a) => a -> b 
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

As can be seen `sqrt` only takes `Floating`s and `floor` only takes `RealFrac`. so I set `a` to `RealFrac` and `Floating`.
Then I specified that `b` would be `Integral` because `floor` gives us a `Integral`.

so my questions is

```hs
newfunction :: (Integral a, RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b 
newfunction a = floor (sqrt (fromIntegral a))
```

Why won't this work?

the actual correct type signature is

```hs
newfunction :: (Integral a, Integral b) => a -> b
```

Comment: No they are both correct but the second one is more general. Given a function `f` with type `(C1 a1, ..., Cn an) => t(a1, ..., an)` then `f` also have the type `(C ai, C1 a1, ..., Cn an) => t(a1, ..., an)`. I.e. adding class constraints cannot make the type wrong. It simply increases the constraints on the type variables.   Obviously to *use* the function you have to satisfy the added constraints, so even though the definition of the function is perfectly well typed you may be unable to actually use it in code due to the lack of instances.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why won't this work?

...but it does:

```hs
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let newfunction :: (Integral a, RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b
Prelude|     newfunction a = floor (sqrt (fromIntegral a))
Prelude| :}
Prelude> :t newfunction 
newfunction :: (Integral a, Integral b, RealFrac a) => a -> b
```

It's just that if you let GHC infer the type signature automatically, it will come up with a simpler/better one for you:

```hs
Prelude> let newfunction a = floor (sqrt (fromIntegral a))
Prelude> :t newfunction 
newfunction :: (Integral b, Integral a) => a -> b
```

But that doesn't mean the manually specified one is wrong — it's just not as general as it could be, which might or might not be what you're after, depending on situation.

As to what it means for something to be *more general* — it's when it makes fewer assumptions and puts fewer requirements/constraints on its inputs; by requiring less, it can work with a larger variety of inputs, and that's called **"more general"**.

---

**Also**, note that the less general version in this case is invalid because you can't really call it with anyhing, but Haskell still allows you to define such a function — the failure will occur at the call site.

```hs
Prelude> :i RealFrac
class (Real a, Fractional a) => RealFrac a where
    ...
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance RealFrac Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
instance RealFrac Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’

Prelude> :i Integral
class (Real a, Enum a) => Integral a where
    ...
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Integral Word -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Integral Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Integral Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
```

— see how not a single type belongs to both `RealFrac` and `Integral` at the same time? If you manually defined `instance RealFrac Integer where ...`, it would work, but that would probably not make sense and would likely violate some type class laws and would thus lead to inconsistent/buggy code.

**So as a general guideline**: start out with the GHC inferred type signature, and only then add additional constraints or make the signature more monomorphic/less polymorphic.

---

**Furthermore**, you could also define these functions [point free](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree), which I think makes them more readable. I've shown below how to transform your current, parentheses-laden versions to point free ones (also called [tacit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming)):

```hs
function x = floor (sqrt x)
function x = floor . sqrt $ x
function   = floor . sqrt

newfunction a = floor (sqrt (fromIntegral a))
newfunction a = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral $ a
newfunction   = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral
```

Comment: as I commented: adding a class constraint (to already existing type variables) can never create problems *at function definition*.

Comment: that's correct; I just didn't see your comment prior to writing this.

Comment: @ErikAllik It works when i type into the interpreter something like new function 10,it gives me a BUNCh of errors?I don't understand how the second is more general? could you explain,thanks a lot

Comment: @Charana: can you PLEASE fix your sentence? I can't parse it! — in any case `newfunction 10` yields `3` when typed into GHCi.

Comment: @ErikAllik Lol sorry,when i type `newfunction 10` with the `newfunction` containing the `RealFrac a` portion i included it doesn't seem to work

Comment: presumably, that's because a value can't be `Integral` and `RealFrac` at the same time, I guess. so just as Bakuriu said: adding a constraint doesn't fail the function definition, but that doesn't mean it can't cause failures at the call site. In other words, the constraints are conflicting, but Haskell won't determine that until you try to call the function. Just use the more general signature and be done with it.

Comment: @ErikAllik Well that explains it,but why did the first function named `function` work? I set `a` to both `Floating` and `RealFrac` ?Why isn't there a conflict here?

Comment: No you didn't. Look again.

Comment: sorry i edited my comment , i set it to `Floating` and `RealFrac`

Comment: because there exist types that are both `Floating` and `RealFrac`; in fact, both `Float` and `Double` belong to both `Floating` and `RealFrac`.